# Connecting a function to QHttp::requestFinished

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, retro-computing

I am using Qt 4.1, the last version that compiles to Windows 98 (although I am running this on Windows XP because I have an AMD processor which cannot virtualize win98). I do not have access to more modern classes like QNetworkManager.

I'm trying to make a method that gets the contents of a url. The class is defined as so:

```cpp
#ifndef __SONG_HPP
#define __SONG_HPP
#include <string>
#include <QWidget>

class Status : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:

public slots:
    void onRequestFinished(int id, bool error);

public:
    Status();
    virtual ~Status(){};
};
#endif
```

And the relevant function is:

```cpp
Status::Status()
{
    QHttp *http = new QHttp("plaza.one");

    QHttpRequestHeader header("GET", "/status");
    header.setValue("Host", "plaza.one");
    http->request(header);

    bool what = QObject::connect(http, SIGNAL(requestFinished(int, bool)), this, SLOT(onRequestFinished(int, bool)));

    std::cout << what << std::endl;
}

void Status::onRequestFinished(int id, bool error)
{
    std::cout << "called" << std::endl;
}
```

QObject::connect returns true, but the function never gets called.

Comment: The [`requestStarted()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qhttp.html#requestStarted) signal only has *one* argument (the id), not two as in your signature. Maybe you wanted to connect to `requestFinished` instead?

Comment: @musicamante I did mean requestFinished yes, I don't know when it got changed to requestStarted. However, the function still never gets called despite true being returned, and this is what I've actually been encountering for the past hour, so I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

My code (after realizing I'd changed it to `requestStarted` at some point without thinking, when it should've been `requestFinished`) was working correctly.

Opening up plaza.one in IE6 reveals that a connection is never actually made. It simply keeps hanging. As it turns out, plaza.one doesn't actually support http and Windows XP does not support the newer TLS/SSL protocols that Cloudflare uses over https.

Comment: That's probably because it assumes that the protocol is http, and nowadays most websites only provide their contents through https, which seems the case of `plaza.one`. Remember that the old http protocol has been considered obsolete and unsecure for modern browsing: not only many websites do not provide its support, but some browser are even in the process of completely prevent its usage. Try changing the QHttp constructor to the [overload](//doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qhttp.html#QHttp-3) that also includes the connection mode (and check the port, which doesn't use the default 80).

Comment: Note that it may also be necessary to add the parent argument to the constructor. I've not enough experience with C++, but it's possible that, without making the `http` object persistent, it'll go out of scope if it doesn't have a parent.

Comment: @musicamante I actually found somebody saying that cloudflare's https doesn't work on windows xp's default networking functions, meaning i would have to redo the networking stack in my program. I ended up just making a redirect to the site on my own site, which does allow for http.